# Unregister all custom object events

Tags: powershell, object, events

I would like to run a command before all this code that unregisters any custom `Register-ObjectEvent`; some command similar to `Remove-Jobs *` for object events. I want to do this because it throws an error if I try to register `$watcher` twice. There is no command called `Get-ObjectEvent`, or else I wouldn't be asking this

```
$folder = "C:\some\path\to\folder"

# File it is watching
$filter = "flag.txt"

# Instantiate Watcher 
$Watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

# EVENT: $filter is created
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"
    Write-Host $path
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there may not be a `Get-ObjectEvent` there *is* a [`Get-EventSubscriber`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/17/manage-event-subscriptions-with-powershell/).

```
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
```

Also, event subscriptions are process-local, so terminating a PowerShell process would remove the subscriptions made within it as well.

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

What I do is have a line before the Register-ObjectEvent:

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -EA 0
```

(give it your event name)

The -EA 0  suppresses any errors thrown.

Comment: The option `-EA` is `ErrorAction`.